# Customize full text text search in PostgreSQL 9.1 in other language

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search

how can i add dictionary,parser, for text search in my native language in PostgreSQL 9.1.
where is contrib folder?

Comment: i want to add new template to add in dictionary.

Comment: The location of contrib depends on how you installed postgres and of course what platform you are on. You have not given enough information to give a meaningful answer.

Comment: i want to search in Bengali (it is my native language ) so english text search configuration will not work in it .so i need to add new dictionary ,template ,parser ,and stemmer for my language i do not now where to add this or what is the format for it.

Comment: i find good information on searching tsearch2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In answer to your narrow question, 9.1 does away with the contrib folder and makes use of 'extensions' as well.  You will want to read the docs on extensions carefully.

From your question it sounds like you are mostly asking about how to get started directory-layout-wise etc.  If you have questions about parsers, stop words, etc. beyond the docs, feel free to ask more questions.

In general the best way to do this is to use the extension system.  What you will do is make sure you have pg_config installed and create a Makefile like:

```
EXTENSION = tsearch_bengali
DATA = $(shell echo *.sql) # add more here as needed

PG_CONFIG = pg_config
PGXS := $(shell $(PG_CONFIG) --pgxs)
include $(PGXS)
```

From there you can just run make and make install and it will install the relevant files into the extensions directory so you can just

```
CREATE EXTENSION tsearch_bengali;
```

Best of luck.  This could be a project that could get some real use!